# python manage.py collectstatic is not copying static files from folder

Tags: python, django, static, assets

I'm doing the [course](https://www.udemy.com/develop-a-shopping-cart-website-with-django-2-and-python-3/), and at class 10 we learn to use `python manage.py collectstatic` . My problem is that it is just collecting the admin assets. (not the assets from the app that I'm developing) Does anyone know why this is happening?

The name of the app is `shop`, and the django project is `perfectcushion`.

```
"""
Django settings for perfectcushion project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '---------------------------------------------------'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'perfectcushion.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'shop','templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'shop.context_processors.menu_links',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'perfectcushion.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

#URL usada quando se referir a arquivos estáticos
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#Pasta onde o manage.py collectstatic vai colocar os arquivos
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
STATIC_FILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)

# Store the media files
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','media')
```

This is the file structure:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── perfectcushion
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── shop
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── context_processors.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── context_processors.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── footer.html
│   │   ├── header.html
│   │   ├── navbar.html
│   │   └── shop
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   └── custom.css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── logo.jpg
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   ├── jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
│   │   └── popper.min.js
│   └── media
│       ├── category
│       └── product
└── staticfiles
    └── admin
        ├── css
        ├── fonts
        ├── img
        └── js

21 directories, 36 files
```

Comment: Will you please share your 'setting.py' and app name?

Comment: The staticfiles folder is generated when I use `python manage.py collectstatic`, but it is not collecting what is inside the folder `static` that is under `perfectcushion` project (same level of the `shop` app). I'm following the instructor class and code, that I have access in the repo. I really don't know why this is happening, :( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your app's assets are not in the static folder inside your app folder. If so, you can define a list of directories (`STATICFILES_DIRS`) in your settings file as follows.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

Comment: Yeah, the assets are in project static folder: ./perfectcushion/static. There is no assets inside the app folder.

Comment: Friend, I didn't see that you wrote correctly the STATICFILES_DIRS. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I made a typo in the folder's name in the `settings.py` file. While actually it is `STATICFILES_DIRS`, it was written as `STATICFILES_DIR`. So just missing S in variable could change the game. :)

Comment: Ups.. me too... How a typo could may you get crazy without understanding why is not working.